# Which ways can I use to restrict access to a website?

Tags: php, symfony, access-control

I'm currently working on ways to restrict access to the company's website. Depending on the user that is logging in, and where the user is trying to login, the site should not open. For example, there is a user-role here that should only access the site from within the company.

The method I'm using to validate the user is check the his/hers public IP address against a table of previously allowed IP adressess, but since this IP address is dynamic, every single time it changes I have to manually allow it again. I'm looking for other ways to detect if the user is within the company, so I can allow it to proceed with the login, but I'm out of ideas.

I've thought about checking if the user is within the company's network, but I don't know if I can do that in PHP. I've also thought about looking for the IP range, but my knowledge about it is quite limited, so I don't believe I can come 
with a reliable solution based on this.

What else can I do about this?

The site is currently running Symfony 4 and is hosted on Azure, if that matters.

Comment: so if a user from the company (who is allowed to see the page) tries to login from home, he is not allowed to see it?

Comment: Exactly. This person is supposed to only be allowed to login from the company, not anywhere else.

Comment: Where is the website hosted?

Comment: It is hosted on Azure.

Comment: have you checked https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions when you have to stay on Azure? Otherwise I'd suggest to host the app within the company's network.

Comment: Could be a solution, but it uses Single sign-on, which I can't support due to technical restrictions (the system I'm trying to protect from external access is connected with another system that I don't have access to its source code, so I can't adapt it for my needs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, most of options that I've found where either out of question because of some requirements that I can't meet of beacuse they don't apply to my situation here.

We did found one solution here: since we have two dedicated internet links, we've routed all outgoing traffic to our website to one of those links. Since they're dedicated and have static IP addresses, all we had to do was add a rule to allow the link's IP.

Problem solved.